# find time difference between different statuses

Tags: sql

[This is my data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3gsHrr5KKf1kXJs4hhDU0Oa4G31rETUMt-xPbp274Y/edit?usp=sharing)  where you can see the time, and statuses change. I want to understand how can I calculate the time difference between each status and then find cumulatively the longness of each status. Will appreciate your help.

```
|41339  |2019-08-04 09:05:13.847|   |0|
|41339  |2019-08-04 09:06:18.787|   |1|
|41339  |2019-08-04 09:07:16.150|   |1|
|41339  |2019-08-04 09:07:37.767|   |1|
|41339  |2019-08-04 09:07:41.933|   |0|
|41339  |2019-08-04 09:08:03.393|   |1|
|41339  |2019-08-04 09:26:52.340|   |2|
```

Comment: Does one of those columns represent the status?  Desire results would help.

Comment: Yes, actually this is motion detection data. 0 is standing, 1 - walking, 2 - driving. So I need to understand the longness of each status

Comment: can you share output you required?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last column is the status, this is a form of gaps-and-islands.  I think you can do what you want with `lag()` to identify where the statuses start and then use `lead()` to get the end:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, datetime,
                lead(datetime) over (partition by col1 order by datetime)
               ) as duration_seconds
from (select t.*, lag(status) over (partition by col1 order by datetime) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status
```